# Liquibase multiple includeAll statements

Tags: liquibase

I was facing problem in including multiple scripts in different sub directories and execute them on same data base using Spring boot 2.1.6.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! It is good that you seem to have answered your own question, but I would like to suggest reading the 'how to ask a question' page at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Without further information, it is very unlikely anyone would have been able to answer your original question.

Answer (score 3):

In my db.changelog-master.yaml I have included following code, that solved my problem.

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - includeAll: 
      path: db/changelog/changes/
  - includeAll:
      path: db/changelog/changes/specific/ 
  - includeAll:
      path: db/changelog/changes/specific/more/
```

And my sql scripts directories are of below structure:

```
db/changelog/changes/
db/changelog/changes/specific/
db/changelog/changes/specific/more/
```